# Jquery failing to add class to elements in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

So I'm adding animation classes to a body element (and the tab element) on the click of the tab using css animation and jquery addClass. It works just fine in Chrome but in Firefox only the tab gets the animation class added...

Here's my jquery;

```
$('.lightboxContentReplace').on('click', '.v4-til-tab-label', function(event) {
var target = $(event.target);
var targetID = target.attr('data-label');
var content = $("[data-content=" + targetID + "]");
$(".v4-til-tab-label").removeClass('tab-label-animation');
$(".v4-til-tab-content").removeClass('tab-content-animation');

target.addClass('tab-label-animation');
content.addClass('tab-content-animation');

$(".v4-til-tab-content").hide();
$("[data-content=" + targetID + "]").show();   });
```

and here's my css;

```
  @-webkit-keyframes tab-label-focus {
  0% { top: 0;}
  100% {top: -5px; border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 188, 141, 0.4)}
}
@-moz-keyframes tab-label-focus {
  0% { top: 0;}
  100% {top: -5px; border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 188, 141, 0.4)}
}
@-o-keyframes tab-label-focus {
  0% { top: 0;}
  100% {top: -5px; border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 188, 141, 0.4)}
}
@keyframes tab-label-focus {
  0% { top: 0;}
  100% {top: -5px; border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0, 188, 141, 0.4)}
}

.tab-label-animation {
  -webkit-animation: tab-label-focus .25s forwards;
  -moz-animation: tab-label-focus .25s forwards;
  -o-animation: tab-label-focus .25s forwards;
  animation: tab-label-focus .25s forwards;
  outline: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes tab-content-focus {
  0% { opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 100%;}
}
@-moz-keyframes tab-content-focus {
  0% { opacity: 0;}
  100% { opacity: 1;}
}
@-o-keyframes tab-content-focus {
  0% { opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 100%;}
}
@keyframes tab-content-focus {
  0% { opacity: 0;}
  100% { opacity: 1;}
}

.tab-content-animation {
  -webkit-animation: tab-content-focus .75s forwards;
  -moz-animation: tab-content-focus .75s forwards;
  -o-animation: tab-content-focus .75s forwards;
  animation: tab-content-focus .75s forwards;
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try `Ctrl + F5` for hard refresh .. And you always need to provide the related `html , css , js...` code when asking to let us try the code

Comment: Provide the html file